# Does Xcode 7 Require Admin Account to Build and Sign App

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, enterprise

In order to build an ipa archive for Enterprise Distribution in Xcode 7, must I log in as an Admin user of the Enterprise Program to perform the build and code sign, or is it sufficient to have the Distribution Certificate, private key and Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile in Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple describes the roles in this document:

- https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

You won't be able to create the needed certificates as a non-admin / non-agent user - but reading your question indicates that you just need to have them delivered to you, so if you already have valid certs and keys you should be good to go signing in as a team member account.

Just set a reminder to leave enough time to remind the admin to renew the certificates since your builds and apps will fail at a known date based on the expiry for the certs you have for the build today.